# Multiple INSERT with SELECT statement and SELECT FROM WHERE simultaneously

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert, insert-into

I have a table shaped like following :

```
CREATE TABLE Cars (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  brand text,
  color text
);
```

You can see the database by following this [**SQLFiddle** link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/740500/2).

You see on the right panel the query I tryied to use in order to insert values using `SELECT` statement.

**QUESTION**

Can someone point me in the right direction to insert values with `SELECT` statement with and without `WHERE` clause simultaneously ?

I tryied the following insert to come by this issue :

```
INSERT INTO Cars (brand, color)
SELECT "mazda", "black",
SELECT Cars.brand, Cars.color FROM Cars WHERE Cars.brand = "ferrari";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO Cars (brand, color)
SELECT "mazda", "black"
UNION ALL
SELECT Cars.brand, Cars.color FROM Cars WHERE Cars.brand = "ferrari";
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5080/1)

Comment: This solution perfectly fits my need.